# I am trying to replace values in a first dataframe with values in a second by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have one data frame like this:

```
      JanDivisor
0          G2/59
```

And a second data frame like this:

```
      JanDivisor
0          G2/44
```

I want to replace all the values in the first data frame in the second data frame with the second data frame values and leave the first data frame values not in the second as are. There's lots of StackOverflow info on replacement but not on specifically replacing it by index.

Comment: post the input dfs in proper readable format

Comment: Thanks.  How do I do that, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'JanDivisor': ['G2/59','do not update']}, index=[0,3])

print(df)

      JanDivisor
0          G2/59
3  do not update

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'JanDivisor': ['G2/44','something1','something2']})

print(df2)

   JanDivisor
0       G2/44
1  something1
2  something2
```

**Code**

```
df['JanDivisor'].update(df2['JanDivisor'])

print(df)

      JanDivisor
0          G2/44
3  do not update
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The perfect solution and very quickly given. The solution, though, seems only possible on the column level. I tried to put all the columns in the brackets, but that gave a key error.

Comment: If you want to update more than one col, you'll be using [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) rather than [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html). More importantly, in that case add the col names of `other` (your `df2`) between *double* angular brackets. E.g., `df.update(df2[['JanDivisor','Col2']])`. If you are fine with just updating any col in `df` that also occurs in `df2`, simply use: `df.update(df2)`.